# Duplicate rows based on field in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` with a fields `count` and `value` and want to transform it to a data frame with the column `value` where each value of `value` is repeated `count` times.

I actually don't have an idea how to do this other than in a loop. Solutions involving `plyr` or `reshape2` (or both) are perfectly acceptable.

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
count value
2     10
1     20
```

to

```
value
10
10
20
```

**Follow-up question**

What if I had 3 fields `value1, value2, value3` which had to be repeated based on `count`?

Comment: @Tyler's answer will work for your follow-up question if you omit the `2` like this: `data.frame(dat[rep(seq_len(dim(dat)[1]), dat$count), , drop = FALSE], row.names=NULL)`

Comment: Please get in the habit of providing code to reproduce your data.frames instead of just showing the output, or describing them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your dataframe was named dat this would work:

```
dat[rep(seq_len(dim(dat)[1]), dat$count), 2]

## [1] 10 10 20
```

If you want it as a dataframe just like you posted:

```
data.frame(dat[rep(seq_len(dim(dat)[1]), dat$count), 2, drop = FALSE], row.names=NULL)

##   value
## 1    10
## 2    10
## 3    20
```

Comment: This solution is better than the `mapply` solution I offered in that it returns a data frame, as the question specified, and it can handle the follow-up question of multiple value columns, as per the comment left by @GSee

Comment: Since this seems to be a somewhat common question, [here's a function for it](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc/blob/master/R/expandrows.R)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `mapply` solution assuming your data frame is called `dat`:

```
do.call("c", (mapply(rep, dat$value, dat$count)))
```

If you have multiple value columns, you could try

```
v <- do.call("c", (mapply(rep, c(dat$value1, dat$value2, dat$value3), dat$count)))

t(matrix(v, numberofvaluecolumns, byrow=T))
```

`numberofvaluecolumns` is just that, the number of value columns you are using.  This returns a matrix, though.  So you would have to be careful if matrices are problematic.